# Spacing around input & select

Tags: css, input

Why is there extra spacing under the inputs that I cannot remove?

http://jsfiddle.net/maciek/guY7P/1/

**HTML**

```
 <table style="width:100px;">
    <tr>
        <td width="75%">
            <input value="INPUT1">
        </td>
        <td width="25%">
            <select>
                <option value="METRE">METRE</option>
                <option value="FOOT">FOOT</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="75%">
            <input value="INPUT1">
        </td>
        <td width="25%">
            <select>
                <option value="METRE">METRE</option>
                <option value="FOOT">FOOT</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="75%">
            <input value="INPUT1">
        </td>
        <td width="25%">
            <input value="INPUT1">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="75%">
            <input value="INPUT1">
        </td>
        <td width="25%">
            <input value="INPUT1">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table, tr, td {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
input, select {
    background:#000;
    border:0;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it's better to try with divs, not in tables

Answer (score 0):

Add `height:100%` to your input rule so the elements take up the full height of the cell.

```
input, select {
    background:#000;
    border:0;
    margin:0px;
    height:100%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/guY7P/6/)**